# c++ protobuf -- where are all the methods in my generated classes?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to parse a protobuf message (in c++) that I receive as a character array.  However, all [the references](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite?csw=1#MessageLite.ParseFromString.details) I've read on how to parse a byte array or string into a protobuf type (e.x. "ParseFromString") use methods that the compiler says aren't defined.

For example,

```
Message* msg;
bool success = ParseFromString(dataString, msg); //error: "ParseFromString" not defined in this scope
MyProtoMsgType* proto = new MyProtoMsgType();
proto->CopyFrom(*msg);
```

The only methods of my message class that are available are the field setters and getters and a couple others (CopyFrom and MergeFrom).  So I have no way of reading the contents of a protobuf message received as a char array!

I would so appreciate help, I've been searching for answers for hours upon hours.

Comment: The reference you've quoted doesn't say that `ParseFromString` is a global function but your code seems to think it is.

Comment: `MyProtoMsgType proto; bool success = proto.ParseFromString(dataString);`

Comment: Look at the example in [the `Message` documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message). Does it look like your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you're using `ParseFromString` as an unbound method. It is actually a method from `Message` or `MessageLite` classes.

```cpp
Message* msg = new Message();
bool success = msg->ParseFromString(dataString);
...
```

If this is not your issue, I am missing something here in your code.